# Request/Proxy error in my Python application

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, proxy, openssl

I try making a request using this proxy but keep getting this same error.

Proxies in the PaaS have worked fine but these are from a new provider and I'm getting this issue with all of their proxies.

```
import requests

proxies = {'http': 'http://104.153.47.242:1374', 'https': 'https://104.153.47.242:1374'}
r = requests.get('https://undefeated.com/products.json',proxies=proxies)
print (r.status_code)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "proxtest.py", line 5, in <module>
   r = requests.get('https://undefeated.com/products.json',proxies=proxies)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
   return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
  return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
   r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 506, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='undefeated.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /products.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_record', 'wrong version number')],)",),))
```

Can you help please?

Comment: where are you running python from? PyCharm? Command Line?

Comment: @Calculus command line

Comment: What operating system

Comment: @Calculus im getting the same issue on my mac and pc

Comment: @JoshBijari: are you even sure that this is a Python issue? Did you successfully use this proxy from within a browser?